# Create custom category attribute - Changes not saving

Tags: category, custom

I created a custom category attribute from the following source:http://ashsmith.co/2013/03/quick-tip-adding-custom-category-attributes-to-magento/

Added new attribute successfully, however, when I changed the name of the field and changed from textarea to dropdown menu, my changes weren't being reflected on backend.  I cleared cache, re-indexed site, and still nothing.  Am I missing something?

Comment: This tutorial uses installer. Once installed if you want to create an other attribute either uninstall  the module or create a new version of it  with the appropriate change of the setup/ .php

Comment: How do you uninstall? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial you have linked uses an installer in the module you create. Once installed, any changes you make to mysql4-install-0.0.1.php will have no effect unless you either uninstall and reinstall the module or create a newer version of your module let's say 0.0.2

**Be very careful and always backup**

**Do not do this on a production server**

**1.Uninstalling**

There is no easy way to uninstall a custom module you have to "mess around" with your DB

**BACKUP BACKUP BACKUP**

**This is not a wiki on uninstalling modules in general**

Notice that this will not delete the already created attribute

1. Make the changes that you want in

   app/code/local/Meteorify/Customcatattrb/sql/customcatattrb_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php
2. Open your DB, find the table core_resource
3. Find the entry 'customcatattrb' '0.0.1' '0.0.1' and Delete it
4. Login to your backend and clear the cache

**2. New Version of your module**

Notice that nor this will delete the already created attribute

1. Duplicate

   `app/code/local/Meteorify/Customcatattrb/sql/customcatattrb_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php`

   in

   `app/code/local/Meteorify/Customcatattrb/sql/customcatattrb_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php`
2. Make the changes that you want in the created file
3. Open `app/code/local/Meteorify/Customcatattrb/etc/config.xml` and in line 5 replace `<version>0.0.1</version>`with `<version>0.0.2</version>`
4. Login to your backend and clear the cache

Comment: Thanks, but how do you uninstall old field?

Comment: This is not the scope of this question. Make a new one please. Did you manage to fix your problem?